# ggplot2 error: Error in signif(x, digits) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a boxplot using ggplot2 in R with the following data:

```
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/105195130/test.txt
```

The R code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(ggplot2)

f<-read.table("test.txt", header=TRUE, sep='\t')

f$Category <- factor(f$Category, levels=unique(as.character(f$Category)))
g<-ggplot(f, aes(Category, Scores)) + stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar', linetype="dashed")
 + geom_boxplot(stat="boxplot", aes(fill=Category)) + geom_vline(linetype="dashed") + 
scale_y_log2()

ggsave("test.pdf")
```

I got the following error:

```
Error in signif(x, digits) : 
Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I tried to google the error and verified if column 'Scores' (2nd column) is non-numeric by looking at mode and class of the file. It looks fine to me. The first column is factor and second column is numeric. I'm unable to understand what is it that I'm doing wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

traceback() prints the following:

```
19: f(unlist(l[numeric]))
18: get(x, envir = this, inherits = inh)(this, ...)
17: scales$y$labels()
16: get(x, envir = this, inherits = inh)(this, ...)
15: coord$compute_ranges(scales)
14: FUN(1:3[[1L]], ...)
13: lapply(seq_along(data), function(i) {
    layer <- layers[[i]]
    layerd <- data[[i]]
    grobs <- matrix(list(), nrow = nrow(layerd), ncol = ncol(layerd))
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(layerd))) {
        for (j in seq_len(ncol(layerd))) {
            scales <- list(x = .$scales$x[[j]]$clone(), y = .$scales$y[[i]]$clone())
            details <- coord$compute_ranges(scales)
            grobs[[i, j]] <- layer$make_grob(layerd[[i, j]], 
                details, coord)
        }
    }
    grobs
})
12: get(x, envir = this, inherits = inh)(this, ...)
11: facet$make_grobs(data, layers, cs)
10: ggplot_build(plot)
9: ggplotGrob(x, ...)
8: grid.draw(ggplotGrob(x, ...))
7: print.ggplot(plot, keep = keep, drop = drop)
6: print(plot, keep = keep, drop = drop)
5: ggsave("test.pdf") at test.R#10
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(ei, envir)
2: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
1: source("test.R")
```

I'm new to R so this doesn't make sense to me, if anyone can explain how can I debug my script using this that will be great.

Comment: What does `traceback()` print?

Comment: @krlmlr: I edited my question with what traceback() prints

Comment: The traceback (position 17) suggests that the error occurs when building the y scale. Does the plot print when you leave out `scale_y_log2()`?

Comment: No the plot doesn't print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My version of **ggplot2** (0.9.3.1) doesn't have a `scale_y_log2` function. But this works instead:

```
library(scales)
g<-ggplot(tmp, aes(Category, Scores)) + 
    stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar', linetype="dashed")+ 
    geom_boxplot(stat="boxplot", aes(fill=Category)) + 
    geom_vline(linetype="dashed") + 
    scale_y_continuous(trans = log_trans(2))
```

I believe that `scale_y_log2` (along with much of the other scales functionality) was moved out of **ggplot2** and into the **scales** package back in the transition to 0.9.0. You should maybe upgrade...?

Comment: Thank you! Its true, I'm working with version 0.8.9 and that sounds awful. But working in an Institute can't really do much. I know they have to upgrade the version now or later but if one upgrades the version, all the R codes will have to be changed to run with new version. I'm saying - I'm not sure if upgrading is wrong or the great difference between different versions of R is wrong.